# How to correctly populate a WIN32_FIND_DATA struct from a ULONGLONG

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

How do I correctly set the **nFileSizeHigh** and **nFileSizeLow** components of a **WIN32_FIND_DATA** structure when  all I have is a file size in ULONGLONG bytes.

Direct casting causes the compiler to complain about possible data loss.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
wfd.nFileSizeLow = (DWORD)totalBytes;
```

Answer (score 2):

The warning is accurate, you are trying to stuff 64 piggies in a 32 pound poke.  Do it like this instead:

```
ULONGLONG size = something;
wfd.nFileSizeHigh = size >> 32;
wfd.nFileSizeLow = size & 0xffffffffUL;
```

Do beware that WIN32_FIND_DATA should normally only be filled by FindFirstFile and FindNextFile().

Comment: Use the `ULARGE_INTEGER` struct instead of shifting  bits manually: `ULARGE_INTEGER ul; ul.QuadPart = ...; wdf.nFileSizeLow = ul.LowPart; wdf.nFileSizeHigh = ul.HighPart;`